# Windows 10 Desktop Chrome Chip-path scale transform ghost line appears

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome

I want to create a animated pie chart by only css and enlarge the sector while hovering,
I found an example code online which perfectly fit with my requirements.
But I found that in Windows 10, Chrome browser (Edge also, but firefox worked perfectly), there will be a ghost line appeared when the sector is animated, there is no problem on macos's chrome.

Any idea why this happened? and how to fix this problem?

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="skills">
  <div id="part1" class="circle animate"></div>
  <div id="part2" class="circle animate"></div>
  <div id="part3" class="circle animate"></div>
  <div id="part4" class="circle animate"></div>
  <div id="part5" class="circle animate"></div>
  <div id="part6" class="circle animate"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#skills {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
}

.animate:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: center center;
}

#part1 {
  background-color: #E64C65;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 0);
}

#part2 {
  background-color: #11A8AB;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
}

#part3 {
  background-color: #4FC4F6;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 36.6% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 36.6% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
}

#part4 {
  background-color: #FFED0D;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 100%, 36.6% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 100%, 36.6% 100%);
}

#part5 {
  background-color: #F46FDA;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 100%);
}

#part6 {
  background-color: #15BFCC;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 0, 50% 0);
}
```

This is the online source I founded,
https://codepen.io/Garnel/pen/eNLaWj

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eztSWXiIHLY

[image: Ghost line]

Comment: It is problem with rendering the animation. It also affects all elements in the graph. You could play with negative margins.

Comment: @GhostPengy What is negative margins?